# How to bundle a Java application to a Mac OS X *.app bundle?

Tags: java, macos, ant, build, jarbundler

I am trying to bundle my Java application to an Mac OS X .app bundle. I am currently using [**appbundler**](https://java.net/downloads/appbundler/appbundler.html) and I followed [Oracle's guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html). The Ant task works fine in Netbeans and the corresponding .app package is built correctly (on Windows). But when trying to execute the .app package to my MacBookPro (OS X 10.7.5), I get the following error in the log:

```
[0x0-0x72072].ch.lawsuite.core.Servitus: Error: Unable to access jarfile LawSuiteSE.jar
```

I already checked the permissions for the .jar file and the execution bits are set for the main-jar and all the jars in the lib-folder.

The application just runs fine when typing the following to the terminal:

```
java -jar /Applications/Servitus.app/Contents/Java/LawSuiteSE.jar --installer
```

For clarification, here's the final folder structure:

```
Servitus.app
    |_Contents
        |_Java
            |_LawSuiteSE.jar
            |_lib
                |_lib1.jar
                |_lib2.jar
                    |_subfolder1
                        |_lib3.jar
                    |_subfolder2
                        |_lib4.jar
                |_etc...
            |_MacOS
                |_JavaAppLauncher
            |_PlugIns
            |_Resources
                |_en.lproj
                    |_Localizable.strings
                |_kplus.icns
        |_Info.plist
        |_PkgInfo
```

By the way, my application has lots of external dependencies, all located in the "lib" folder which are properly linked by the class-path property within the MANIFEST.MF file of the executable main-jar file "LawSuiteSE.jar". Do I need to copy these libs within the appbundle-ant-task or is it okay to copy them subsequently by hand?

I also tried to build the application and the corresponding .app package on the MacBook Pro, but the same error message.

Here's my Ant-task:

```
<!-- Define the appbundler task -->
<taskdef name="bundleapp" classname="com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask"/>
<!-- Create the app bundle -->
<target name="bundle-macosx">
    <bundleapp outputdirectory="macosx"
        name="Servitus"
        displayname="Servitus"
        identifier="ch.lawsuite.core.Servitus"
        shortversion="1.0"
        applicationCategory="public.app-category.business"
        icon="src/ch/lawsuite/data/icons/gmbh/osx/kplus.icns"
        mainclassname="ch.lawsuite.core.Servitus">
        <classpath file="dist/LawSuiteSE.jar"/>
        <argument value="--installer"/>
    </bundleapp>
</target>
```

EDIT: I meanwhile replaced the JavaAppLauncher in Contents/MacOS with a small run script (start.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
java -Xms256m -XX:PermSize=128m -jar /Users/salocinx/Workspace/LawSuiteSE.app/Contents/Java/LawSuiteSE.jar --installer
```

Then I also replaced the value for the key *CFBundleExecutable* in *Info.plist* from *JavaAppLauncher* to *start.sh*.

Now it works fine, but how can I use a relative path to the jar-executable? Something like "../Java/LawSuiteSE.jar" doesn't work and gives me the same error as before. Is there any constant pointing to the current app-folder, something like "$APP_ROOT" so that the script could look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -Xms256m -XX:PermSize=128m -jar $APP_ROOT/Contents/Java/LawSuiteSE.jar --installer
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the symlinks working? Generally, when building on windows, the symlinks are broken.

Comment: Okay I checked and updated my symlinks on the MacBook Pro by following this guide: http://www.monkehworks.com/set-java-7-as-default-jvm-on-mac-osx-mountain-lion. But I does still not work. Next I will try to build my app on the MacBook.

Comment: Building the entire project and bundling the package on the Mac did not help... still same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to copy these libs within the appbundle-ant-task

Yes, you should mention all the required libraries in `classpath` elements.  The bundler will then copy them all to the appropriate place inside the bundle (only JAR files that are *directly* under `Contents/Java` will go onto the classpath when the bundle is run, JARs in subdirectories are ignored).  You should also use dots instead of slashes in the mainclassname.

```
<bundleapp outputdirectory="macosx"
    name="Servitus"
    displayname="Servitus"
    identifier="ch.lawsuite.core.Servitus"
    shortversion="1.0"
    applicationCategory="public.app-category.business"
    icon="src/ch/lawsuite/data/icons/gmbh/osx/kplus.icns"
    mainclassname="ch.lawsuite.core.Servitus">
    <classpath file="dist/LawSuiteSE.jar"/>
    <classpath dir="lib" includes="*.jar" />
    <argument value="--installer"/>
</bundleapp>
```

---

Edit

> Now it works fine, but how can I use a relative path to the jar-executable

You can use `dirname $0` to get the path to your bundle's `Contents/MacOS`, and take a relative path from there.  You should probably also make an explicit reference to the public JRE rather than relying on `java` being on your PATH, as that will only work if the target machine has a *JDK* installed, not if it only has a *JRE*.  Installing the JDK will install the public JRE as well, so it's safe in that case too.

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT_DIR="`dirname $0`"
exec "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java" \
  -Xms256m -XX:PermSize=128m -jar "$SCRIPT_DIR/../Java/LawSuiteSE.jar" --installer
```

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for your suggestion. Now the bundler copies and flattens all the .jar files within my lib folder to Contents/Java. I also adjusted my MANIFEST.MF to directly looking for the .jars in the app-root folder instead of app-root/lib. But still the very same problem. Btw. is there really no way to keep up the folder structure within the lib-folder? My external libs have themselves heavy dependencies to a lot of other jar-libs in a clearly defined folder structure within the lib-folder. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @salocinx The native launcher stub inserted into the bundle by the bundler task creates it's classpath by enumerating all the jar files that are contained in the `Contents/Java` directory (and only that directory, no subdirs), and executes the mainclassname - this behaviour is hard coded in the stub and is not negotiable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Ian. Okay these are bad news. Is there any work-around to launch my application with some kind of a script or something similar out of an .app-bundle? My application basically works just fine on the Mac when directly launching with "java -jar Servitus.jar --installer", but I'm really interested in an .app-bundle... :-) Any further ideas?

Comment: @salocinx you can certainly construct a bundle by hand, and the main "binary" in `Contents/MacOS` can be a shell script that delegates to `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java`.  This is the approach I use for [GATE](http://gate.ac.uk), though it's a bit more complex in that case as there's a second level of indirection (it's a cross-platform tool, the script inside the `.app` bundle delegates to another shell script, which other platforms would call directly).

Comment: Hi Ian, that's exactly what I meant. Meanwhile I wrote a small start.sh script and linked it with the CFBundleExecutable key in the Info.plist. The only problem remaining is that I need to provide the full path to the .jar-executable within the script, with relative paths it doesn't work... is there a placeholder that points to the current .app-folder like $APP_ROOT or something similar? Please have a look on the original question above, I added an "EDIT" section to describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: @salocinx I've added a suggestion using the fact that a script knows its own path via `$0`

Comment: Hey Ian - thank you very much, this issue had been on my todo list for 9 months now and I am very happy to have solved it finally :-D Btw. I checked GATE and this looks very promising, maybe I'll find an application in my project :-)